# Are the sounds "j" and "w" (in international phonetic alphabet) vowels or consonants?

Tags: prononciation, linguistique, phonétique

The question is on words like these, with their pronunciation in IPA within brackets:

> lumière [lymjɛʀ], premier [pʀəmje], boire [bwaʀ], jouet [ʒwɛ]

**Question**

Are the sounds [j] and [w] considered vowels or consonants?

Also, which syllabication would be correct?

> (a) lu•mi•ère, pre•mi•er, bo•ire, jou•et
>
> (b) lu•mière, pre•mier, boire, jouet

If you need context for the question of syllables:  In a poem requiring twelve syllables per line how many will e.g. lumière take up?

**Background**

This is what I found in Littré:

> [lumière](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/lumiere) [lu-miè-r'], [premier](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/premier) [pre-mié], [boire](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/boire) [boi-r'], [jouet](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/jouet) [jou-è]

But I am not sure if the dash represents syllabification.

Comment: Why would [j] and [w] be considered as consonent ? A sound is considered as a vowel if you can do it without closing your mouth (with lips or tongue). Except nasal vowel, which are semi-vowels.

Comment: @Random nasal vowels are plain vowels, not semi-vowels. The fact they are transcripted with a vowel/consonent combination doesn't change their phonetics.

Comment: @jlliagre Indeed. I'm pretty sure I remember my teacher talking about nasal vowel as a particular category... I can't remember why... Maybe because vocal cords vibrate, whereas on simple vowel they don't... (It was for speech recognition purpose...)

Comment: Vocal cords usually vibrate in either cases. Nasal vowels are special because some air flow though the nose when pronouncing them, unlike oral vowels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[j] and [w] are considered [semivowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel) a.k.a. glides, in French either *[semi-voyelles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-voyelle)* or *semi-consonnes*.

In poetry, syllables would be split that way:

- lu•mière or lu•miè•re
- pre•mier
- boire or boi•re
- jou•et

*Lumière* and *boire* have one less syllable when followed by a vowel, a mute h or at the end of a verse.

Note that in poetry *jouet* changes its pronunciation from the monosyllabic [ʒwɛ] to to the disyllabic [ʒu.ɛ]

Comment: So in meter semivowels are consonants, and Littré was giving me syllabification based on the word being followed by a vowel etc. Thanks again!